# Optimize/correct behaviour of a combination of Python multiprocessing Queue and Processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I have a function that uses multiprocessing's Queues and Processes to execute a task, but sometimes it gets stuck and it has unexplained behaviours. I would appreciate if someone could optimize this code to do the same final task in a better way, maybe even a more pythonic way.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import numpy as np


def start_multicore_task(nres, cores_per_task):
    in_data = Queue()
    out_data = Queue()


    iterator = set(range(nres))
    for res1 in iterator:
        # "others" are every value in "iterator" higher than res1 itself
        others = list(iterator - set(range(res1)) - {res1})
        if len(others) > 0:
            # a check because the last value in "iterator" won't have any value higher than itself
            in_data.put((res1, others))

            
    def calculate_row(nres, in_data, out_data):
        "funciton to fill a row of what will be a square numpy array"
        while not in_data.empty():
            res, others = in_data.get()
            row = np.zeros((nres,))

            for other in others:
                # in my real code, which also doesn't work, obviously this performs a more
                # complex calculation to add to the row[other] array position
                row[other] = other

            out_data.put((res, row))
            
        return


    ps = []
    for _ in range(cores_per_task):
        p = Process(target=calculate_row,
                    args=(nres, in_data, out_data)) 
        p.start()
        ps.append(p)
    
    for p in ps:
        p.join()
        
    
    corr = np.zeros((nres, nres))
    for _ in range(out_data.qsize()):
        res, row = out_data.get()
        corr[res, :] = row
    
        
    return corr
```

Sometimes calling `start_multicore_task(50, 3)` works and sometimes it gets stuck (if I put some `print`s around, it gets stuck in the last element of the in_data), and `start_multicore_task(300, 3)` has never worked (also stuck in the last element of the `in_data`). I don't know what is happening.

Comment: what is your os?

Comment: Your code shouldn't even run on windows since you are attempting to pickle a factory function

Comment: @Charchit Linux, with `multiprocess` that uses dill to pickle the problem still remains.

Comment: would you be open to using "spawn" method to start the process rather than the default on your os, i.e, "fork"?

Comment: @Charchit not really, I have had bad experiences doing that in the past. Also I remember it not being usable/useful for some OS? I just solved my problem and I'm going to update my question with what I've finally done. Thanks for your implication!

Comment: I see that you switched to using a `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Your problem  using queues and processes getting stuck results from trying to `join` the child process prior to consuming all items it has placed on the queue. Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=queue#multiprocessing.Queue), in particular the warnings. Also, as mentioned, method `multiprocessing.Queue.empty` is not reliable.

Answer (score 2):

See my comment concerning joining child processes before you have consumed items they have put to a `multiprocessing.Queue`, which can cause you to hang.

If I understand your code correctly, `cores_per_task` is poorly named since it represents the *total* number of cores (child processes) available to process *all* the tasks. But I will continue to use that name.

Since method `multiprocessing.queue.empty` is not reliable, if you have N processes doing `get` calls against a queue, you should add to the queue N *sentinel* items, which cannot be mistaken for a normal item, and is used to signify that there is no more data on the queue. Here we can use `None` as the sentinel. Similarly, since the main process must `get` all the items from the output queue prior to joining the child processes, each child process should add a `None` sentinel record when it has completed writing results to the queue. The main process only has to do blocking `get` calls and count the number of sentinel records it sees. When that number is N, it knows it had retrieved all the results:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import numpy as np


def start_multicore_task(nres, cores_per_task):
    in_data = Queue()
    out_data = Queue()


    iterator = set(range(nres))
    for res1 in iterator:
        # "others" are every value in "iterator" higher than res1 itself
        others = list(iterator - set(range(res1)) - {res1})
        if len(others) > 0:
            # a check because the last value in "iterator" won't have any value higher than itself
            in_data.put((res1, others))
    for _ in range(cores_per_task):
        in_data.put(None) # sentinel marking no more data to each child process


    def calculate_row(nres, in_data, out_data):
        "funciton to fill a row of what will be a square numpy array"
        while True:
            item = in_data.get()
            if item is None: # sentinel?
                break
            res, others = item
            row = np.zeros((nres,))

            for other in others:
                # in my real code, which also doesn't work, obviously this performs a more
                # complex calculation to add to the row[other] array position
                row[other] = other

            out_data.put((res, row))

        out_data.put(None) # put sentinel

    ps = []
    for _ in range(cores_per_task):
        p = Process(target=calculate_row,
                    args=(nres, in_data, out_data))
        p.start()
        ps.append(p)


    corr = np.zeros((nres, nres))
    sentinels_seen = 0
    while sentinels_seen < cores_per_task:
        item = out_data.get()
        if item is None: # sentinel
            sentinels_seen += 1
        else:
            res, row = item
            corr[res, :] = row

    for p in ps:
        p.join()

    return corr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(start_multicore_task(10, 4))
```

Prints:

```None
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
 [0. 0. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
 [0. 0. 0. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7. 8. 9.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 8. 9.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 9.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Alternatively, instead of the child processes putting *sentinel* items on the output queue, you can use a `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` for `in_data`. As soon as a child process has processed an input item from `in_data` and put its result on `out_data`, it calls `in_data.task_done()` signifying that the item had been fully processed. Then the main process only has to call `in_data.join()` to wait for all results to have been generated followed by *non-blocking* calls `in_data.get_no_wait()` to retrieve the results. When this returns an `Empty` exception, we know that all results have been processed.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, JoinableQueue
from queue import Empty
import numpy as np


def start_multicore_task(nres, cores_per_task):
    in_data = JoinableQueue()
    out_data = Queue()


    iterator = set(range(nres))
    for res1 in iterator:
        # "others" are every value in "iterator" higher than res1 itself
        others = list(iterator - set(range(res1)) - {res1})
        if len(others) > 0:
            # a check because the last value in "iterator" won't have any value higher than itself
            in_data.put((res1, others))
    for _ in range(cores_per_task):
        in_data.put(None) # sentinel marking no more data to each child process


    def calculate_row(nres, in_data, out_data):
        "funciton to fill a row of what will be a square numpy array"
        while True:
            item = in_data.get()
            if item is None: # sentinel?
                in_data.task_done() # show we have completed processing this item
                break
            res, others = item
            row = np.zeros((nres,))

            for other in others:
                # in my real code, which also doesn't work, obviously this performs a more
                # complex calculation to add to the row[other] array position
                row[other] = other

            out_data.put((res, row))
            in_data.task_done() # show we have completed processing this item

    ps = []
    for _ in range(cores_per_task):
        p = Process(target=calculate_row,
                    args=(nres, in_data, out_data))
        p.start()
        ps.append(p)

    # wait for all results to have been created:
    in_data.join()

    corr = np.zeros((nres, nres))
    try:
        while True:
            res, row = out_data.get_nowait()
            corr[res, :] = row
    except Empty:
        pass

    for p in ps:
        p.join()

    return corr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(start_multicore_task(10, 4))
```

Finally, we can eliminate having to put sentinel records to the input queue by just making the child processes *daemon* processes that will now loop forever trying to get more input but will automatically terminate when the main process terminates:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, JoinableQueue
from queue import Empty
import numpy as np


def start_multicore_task(nres, cores_per_task):
    in_data = JoinableQueue()
    out_data = Queue()


    iterator = set(range(nres))
    for res1 in iterator:
        # "others" are every value in "iterator" higher than res1 itself
        others = list(iterator - set(range(res1)) - {res1})
        if len(others) > 0:
            # a check because the last value in "iterator" won't have any value higher than itself
            in_data.put((res1, others))


    def calculate_row(nres, in_data, out_data):
        "funciton to fill a row of what will be a square numpy array"
        # This loop never terminates, but we are now a daemon process and
        # thus this process will terminate when the main process terminates:
        while True:
            res, others = in_data.get()
            row = np.zeros((nres,))

            for other in others:
                # in my real code, which also doesn't work, obviously this performs a more
                # complex calculation to add to the row[other] array position
                row[other] = other

            out_data.put((res, row))
            in_data.task_done() # show we have completed processing this item

    for _ in range(cores_per_task):
        p = Process(target=calculate_row,
                    args=(nres, in_data, out_data), daemon=True)
        p.start()

    # wait for all results to have been created:
    in_data.join()

    corr = np.zeros((nres, nres))
    try:
        while True:
            res, row = out_data.get_nowait()
            corr[res, :] = row
    except Empty:
        pass

    return corr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(start_multicore_task(10, 4))
```

And if you are using a multiprocessing pool, since `map` returns its results in task submission order, there is no need for the worker function `calculate_row` to return back a tuple whose first element is `res`. The value of what `res` would have been had it been returned can now be deduced just by the order that the row is returned. That is, we can `enumerate` the rows returned with a starting index of 1. Also, there is no need to explicitly call `shutdown` on the pool since it will be implicitly called when the `with Pool(cores_per_task) as p:` block terminates:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

def calculate_row(in_data, nres):
    "function to fill a row of what will be a square numpy array"
    res, others = in_data
    row = np.zeros((nres,))

    for other in others:
        # in my real code, which also doesn't work, obviously this performs a more
        # complex calculation to add to the row[other] array position
        row[other] = other

    return row

def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, pool_size * 4)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

def start_multicore_task(nres, cores_per_task):
    in_data = []
    iterator = set(range(nres))
    for res1 in iterator:
        # "others" are every value in "iterator" higher than res1 itself
        others = list(iterator - set(range(res1)) - {res1})
        if len(others) > 0:
            # a check because the last value in "iterator" won't have any value higher than itself
            in_data.append((res1, others))

    with Pool(cores_per_task) as p:
        # No need to convert items to a list and by no doing so,
        # we can process the results as they are generated without having to
        # wait for all the results to have been generated
        chunksize = compute_chunksize(len(in_data), cores_per_task)
        results = p.map(partial(calculate_row, nres=nres), in_data, chunksize=chunksize)

        corr = np.zeros((nres, nres))
        for res, row in enumerate(results, start=1):
            corr[res, :] = row

    return corr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(start_multicore_task(10, 4))
```

Comment: Great alternatives! I had seen the use of sentinels in other questions/answers but I couldn't figure out how to implement them here. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer providing a third alternative that eliminates having to use sentinels.

Comment: And I have added a method that uses a multiprocessing pool, which is slightly different than yours since there is no need for `calculate_row` to return a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here:

```
def calculate_row(nres, in_data, out_data):
        "funciton to fill a row of what will be a square numpy array"
        while not in_data.empty():
            res, others = in_data.get()
```

Check the docs for multiprocessing.Queue.empty:

"Return True if the queue is empty, False otherwise. *Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this is not reliable.*"

Your Queue has multiple consumers running simultaneously, the empty() function will sometimes return False but another Process happens to grab the last item from the Queue before the in_data.get() statement executes.  That will cause a freeze, and it will happen randomly.  I think this explains why your program *sometimes* doesn't process the last element.

Try it this way:

```
def calculate_row(nres, in_data, out_data):
    while True:
        try:
            res, others = in_data.get(block=False)
        except queue.Empty:
            break
```

The rest of the method is unchanged.  This should work because you fill the Queue before launching any consumer Process.

Warning: I had no way of running this myself.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I changed from Queues and Processes to a `concurrent.futures`'s `ProcessPoolExecutor` and, as hinted by @Charchit, I had to move my mapped function `calculate_row` to the top-level of the module so that it could be pickled. This solution works great for me because, besides this problem, I need to run the `start_multicore_task` inside a `multiprocess.Pool` itself, which is a daemonic process that can't spawn children of its own, while a Pool from concurrent.futures runs smoothly inside it.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool
from functools import partial
import numpy as np


def calculate_row(in_data, nres):
    "function to fill a row of what will be a square numpy array"
    res, others = in_data
    row = np.zeros((nres,))

    for other in others:
        # in my real code, which also doesn't work, obviously this performs a more
        # complex calculation to add to the row[other] array position
        row[other] = other

    return res, row




def start_multicore_task(nres, cores_per_task):
    in_data = []
    iterator = set(range(nres))
    for res1 in iterator:
        # "others" are every value in "iterator" higher than res1 itself
        others = list(iterator - set(range(res1)) - {res1})
        if len(others) > 0:
            # a check because the last value in "iterator" won't have any value higher than itself
            in_data.append((res1, others))

            
        
    with Pool(cores_per_task) as p:
        results = list(p.map(partial(calculate_row, nres=nres), in_data, chunksize=len(in_data)/(cores_per_task*2)))
        p.shutdown()
        
    
    corr = np.zeros((nres, nres))
    for result in results:
        res, row = result
        corr[res, :] = row
    
        
    return corr
```

Comment: I believe you are using *chunksize* inappropriately. It specifies "chunks" or "batches" of tasks that each pool process will take of the input queue together to process. In the extreme case of where it specifies the total number of input tasks (size of `in_data`), then all the tasks would be pulled off the input queue by a single pool process and you would have no parallel processing because the other pool processes would remain idle because there is nothing left on the  input queue. So it's not how this *chunksize* should relate to the process pool size (`cores_per_task`). (more....)

Comment: By not specifying a *chunksize*, which is perfectly okay unless the number of tasks being submitted is very large, ensures that there are no idle pool processes that have no work to do while other processes have multiple tasks left to process. Let's say you have 8 cores so you set the *chunksize* to 8. You now submit 32 tasks. They will be on the task input queue as 4 chunks of 8 tasks. Only 4 pool processes will be doing any work. What then is the point of having a pool size of 8?

Comment: @Booboo you're right! Since I expect my number of tasks (size of in_data) to be around ~300 always, I'm going to use `chunksize=len(in_data)/(cores_per_task*2)` (will change it in the answer), which at least in theory sounds nice to me. Thanks!

Comment: Just for your information, if you do multiprocessing with class `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` and call `map` without specifying a *chunksize* (this argument defaults to `None`), then *chunksize* will be computed as follows: `chunksize, remainder = divmod(len(in_data), cores_per_task * 4); if remainder: chunksize += 1`.